# Ring of Polynomials with two variables

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I am working on the ring $R$ of polynomials with two variables over some field,

and I have the ideal $J$ generated by $x^2$ and $xy$.

I am considering the module $R/J$ over $R$;

and I get to a point where I have $\bar{p} \in R/J$ such that $yp \in J$ and $ xp \in J$.

What can I say about $\bar{p} $ now, in which "quotient"  is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every class $\overline{p} \in R/J$, there exist a polynomial $q(y)$ and constants $a,b$ such that $p(x,y) = y\cdot q(y)+ a\cdot x + b$ is a representant of the class $\overline{p}$.

Notice that $x\cdot p(x,y) - bx \in J$ and $y\cdot p(x,y) - y(b+ y\cdot q(y)) \in J$. We deduce from this that the assumptions $xp \in J$ and $yp \in J$ imply that $b=0$ and $q=0$.

Thus, $\overline{p} = a\cdot x + J$ for some constant $a$.

Comment: So $\bar{p} \in ??$ as a quotient module.

Comment: @KerryH: I don't understand what you want, maybe $\overline{p} \in \langle x\rangle_R/J$? but the last line is more precise than this.

Comment: Yeah I want something like that.. I am trying to find the kernel of some map. Anyway, can I say $\bar{p} \in (x)/J$ when you said that $a$ has to be constant, that is I can't multiply $x$ by a polynomial right?

Comment: I said that we *can* choose $a$ to be a constant. If it is the kernel of $\overline{p} \in R/J \mapsto (x \overline{p}, y \overline{p}) \in (R/J)^2$ you are looking for, it is indeed $(x)/J$.